# AWS CloudWatch Logs to Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to push AWS CloudWatch Logs to Kafka and trying to find out the best architecture to achieve this.

One approach I was thinking of is to
-> Subscribe to log group events on cloud watch by selecting log group and clicking on
Action ->Stream to AWS Lambda and select the lambda that will stream data to Kafka.

So I might have to write some Java/Python function to write logs to Kafka from Lambda. However, I am not sure whether this is the right design.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [CloudWatch Logs Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-aws-cloudwatch-logs/current/overview.html) for Kafka Connect? It should be pretty straightforward to use and doesn't require any code writing (unfortunately, I only used jdbc connectors so I can't tell for sure how hard it is to configure it).